# looping through multiple arrays and inserting into SQL

Tags: php, sql, loops

I have a form that once submitted some of its result are stored in arrays, example:

(The form has multiple lines with the same input names)

`<select name="product[]">` once submitted goes into `$_GET['product']`

if I do:

```
// Product ID's
foreach($_GET['product'] as $name => $prodvalue) {
print "$name : $prodvalue<br>";
}
```

the following is returned:

0 : 9

1 : 10

2 : 11

3 : 12

As well as the Product ID's I have 2 other form input structured the same way, so my question is how do I loop through each of the $_GET's (`$_GET['product']`, `$_GET['linequantity']` and `$_GET['lineprice']`) to add each of them to multiple SQL table rows? Also there will be *other records* that need to be entered, but, these will be constant, so for instance, if 3 rows are to be added then the *other records* will be the same for each of the 3 rows.

Please help me, I'm goin' nuts!

B.

**EDIT:**

The table is called: order_lines

Value => Field

$_GET['product'] => product_id

$_GET['linequantity'] => unit_price

$_GET['lineprice'] => qty

$unh => unh

There are more, but, i can work it out from there.

Comment: We could give you a much more accurate answer if you gave some idea of what the table this is going into looks like. What columns are you populating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the same number of items in each collection, I would go with something like this:

```
$staticValue1 = $_GET['value1'];
$staticValue2 = $_GET['value2'];

foreach($_GET['product'] as $name => $prodvalue) {
  $name = my_escape($name);
  $prodvalue = my_escape($prodvalue);
  $linequantity = my_escape($_GET['linequantity'][$name]);
  $lineprice = my_escape($_GET['lineprice'][$name]);
  if (checkFormat($linequantity, $lineprince, $prodvalue, $name, $staticValue1, $staticValue2) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO <table> (qty, unit_price, product, name, static_value_1, static_value_2) VALUES ".
           "(".$linequantity.", '".$lineprice."', '".$prodvalue."', '".$name."', '".$staticValue1."', '".$staticValue2."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
  }
}

function my_escape($input) {
  //filter chars that will cause problems in the database
  //  then return the filtered values; depends on db
  //  usually this means encoding quotes, at the very least

  return str_replace("'","/'",$input);
}

function checkFormat($linequantity, $lineprince, $prodvalue, $name, $staticValue1, $staticValue2) {
  //use a series of comparisons to return true or false
  //  based on whether or not ALL inputs match the expected range of values

  if (!(is_numeric($linequantity)) return false;

  ... //<-- more comparisons

  return true; // <-- reaching this means it did not fail on any checks
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, if i echo $query i get this:

INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES (0, '1', '', '', 'Array', 'Array', '9')INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES (0, '1', '', '', 'Array', 'Array', '10')INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES (0, '1', '', '', 'Array', 'Array', '11')INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES (0, '1', '', '', 'Array', 'Array', '12')

Comment: You're getting multiple repetitions because it's echoing in a loop. So really, one query is `INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES (0, '1', '', '', 'Array', 'Array', '9')`, which is almost right. Looks like it's not quite getting the desired values for qty, unit_price, and possibly unh/o_id. I'll update to deal with the issue for qty/unit_price.

Comment: Updated. Should work now, except that it may still have no value for unh and o_id, since those are set elsewhere. The key is adding `[$name]` to the end of the `$_GET['']` assignments.

Comment: sorry, still getting this:

INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES ('3', '1', '8ea946deef1c4660ab2b8fb01753092f', '1', '65.00', '1', '9')INSERT INTO order_lines (c_id, d-id, unh, o_id, unit_price, qty, product_id) VALUES ('3', '1', '8ea946deef1c4660ab2b8fb01753092f', '1', '69.00', '1', '12')

Which wont enter into the db...

Comment: Again, each `INSERT ...` instance is a separate `$query` from a separate pass through the loop. You can verify this by putting a separation character at the end of the line where you output it. Something like `echo $query."\n<br\>\n";`

Comment: Found the problem, it was d-id - SQL don't like the hyphen...Thanks Load for your help....

Comment: So the problem is that at least one of the values in the VALUES section does not match up with the type that the DB expects for that field. Can you tell me exactly what error it is giving you, and what the types are for these fields in the db (specifically for `unh`)?

Comment: That makes sense too. I overlooked that some dbs consider `-` to be a special char. Glad it got sorted out :)

Answer (score 1):

If the keys of all form field arrays are equal then you can use the name of one to reference the other:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_GET['product'] as $name => $value) {
    $values[] = array($value, $_GET['linequantity'][$name], $_GET['lineprice'][$name]);
}
```

This creates an array in which each element is an array with related fields: