# Insert multiple arrays values to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 1 variable

$last_id

and 4 Arrays:

```
$outA Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )
$outB Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )
$sub_min_points Array ( [0] => 700 [1] => 800 [2] => [3] => 500 )
$sub_max_points Array ( [0] => 200 [1] => 400 [2] => [3] => 300)

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO `position_grading` 
                                (`position_id`, `grading_sub_id`,
                                `grading_main_id`,sub_min_points,
                                sub_max_points) 
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss",$last_id, $d1, $d2, $sub_min_points, $sub_max_points);
```

I used this to fetch data from arrays and insert it to database

```
    $sub_elements = $_POST['sub_elements'];
    $outA = array();
    $outB = array();
    foreach($sub_elements as $value)
    {
        list($x, $y) = explode(":",$value);
        $outA[] = $x;
        $outB[] = $y;
    }

    foreach(array_combine($outA, $outB) AS $d1 => $d2) {
        $d1;
        $d2;
        $sub_min_points =  $sub_min_points[$d1];
        $sub_max_points = $sub_max_points[$d1];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

when I delete these two lines it's working and send data to the database

```
        $sub_min_points =  $sub_min_points[$d1];
        $sub_max_points = $sub_max_points[$d1];
```

I want to use foreach to fetch 4 arrays at once this is my problem.

The problem fetch 2 arrays and use $d1 as a key

I tried the solution here
[looping through multiple arrays and inserting into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483897/looping-through-multiple-arrays-and-inserting-into-sql)

it's not working with me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are actually having?

Comment: *i's working don't know how to fix this* what do u wanna fix when its working?

Comment: You cannot store a PHP array into a table column as a raw PHP array.

Comment: You could try `serialize()` or `json_encode()` on the arrays to turn them into a string and store that

Comment: when I delete the lines i mentioned foreach working and insert the data to database

Comment: I want to use foreach to fetch multiple arrays this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixed my problem

```
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("
        INSERT INTO 
              `position_grading` 
                  (`position_id`, `grading_sub_id`, `grading_main_id`,sub_min_points,sub_max_points) 
        VALUES    
              (?,?,?,?,?)");

        foreach($sub_min_points AS $index => $code){
        $code;
        $d1 = $sub_max_points[$index];
        $d2 = $outA[$index];
        $d3 = $outB[$index];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```